# How can I get the most recent log entries across multiple log tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 instance that hosts multiple databases, one for each client. They each have a log table. I wish to see the TOP 20 rows from the most recent log entries from whichever database log that was most recently saved to.

Here is an example of my attempt with only two databases. I feel like there is a better way (I put the `WHERE` clause in to help performance as there are many million rows in the log tables)

```
SELECT TOP 10
    *
FROM
(   SELECT TOP 10
        B.Description,
        B.Created,
        B.Type,
        B.MachineName
    FROM 
        [BAB].[dbo].[PatientActivityLog] B
    WHERE
        B.Created > (GETDATE() - 1)     
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 10 
        C.Description,
        C.Created,
        C.Type,
        C.MachineName
    FROM
        [BAC].[dbo].[PatientActivityLog] C
    WHERE
        C.Created > (GETDATE() - 1)
) x
ORDER BY
    x.Created DESC
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to avoid duplicate check. Also add an order by inside the `TOP 20` sub query.

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 20
        Description, Created, Type, MachineName
    FROM [BAB].[dbo].[ActivityLog]
    WHERE Created > (GETDATE() - 1)
    ORDER BY Created DESC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 20
        Description, Created, Type, MachineName
    FROM [BAC].[dbo].[ActivityLog]
    WHERE Created > (GETDATE() - 1)
    ORDER BY Created DESC
) x
ORDER BY
    x.Created DESC
```

Comment: Is it possible without using a UNION within an INNER QUERY?  It doesn't seem like an elegant solution as I will need to repeat that INNER UNION many times, one for each separate database.  But it does work.

Comment: You could use a cursor to loop to each database.

Comment: OUCH - That sounds worse..  Thank you